# Variables largest and smallest are not being replaced from the second function to the first

Tags: python-3.x

I have to design the following program:
design a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of numbers. the user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and the smallest number entered.

This is what I have gotten so far:

```
def main():
    inputNum = 0
    largest = 1
    smallest = 10000
    while inputNum != -99:
        inputNum = int(input("enter a number"))
        if inputNum == -99:
            break
        lgsm(inputNum, largest, smallest)
    print("The largest value is",largest, "the smallest value is",smallest)


def lgsm(inputNum, largest, smallest):
    if inputNum > largest:
        largest = inputNum

    elif inputNum < smallest:
        smallest = inputNum
main()
```

When I try to run it the values for smallest and largest remain the same
I don't really know what to do from here

Expected output:

```
enter a number 1

enter a number 2

enter a number 5

enter a number 6

enter a number -99
```

The largest value is 1 the smallest value is 10000

Comment: And what is wrong with the given code?

Comment: its returning the original values for smallest and largest

Comment: Please add **all explanation** to the question, not to the comment section. Additionally, explain what you've tried to spot the problem

Comment: ive added all the explanation to the question

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried printing `largest` and `smallest` after each iteration?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference helps?

Comment: yes i have tried that but it prints out either the smallest or the largest every time it asks for another number

Comment: mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

Python does not use "call by reference", but "call by assignment". That means that the variables you've changed within the scope of `lgsm` are not passed to the outer scope of `main` automatically. To do so, you should **return** the changed values:

```
def main():
    inputNum = 0
    largest = 1
    smallest = 10000
    while inputNum != -99:
        inputNum = int(input("enter a number"))
        if inputNum == -99:
            break
        largest, smallest = lgsm(inputNum, largest, smallest)
    print("The largest value is",largest, "the smallest value is",smallest)


def lgsm(inputNum, largest, smallest):
    if inputNum > largest:
        largest = inputNum

    elif inputNum < smallest:
        smallest = inputNum
    return (largest, smallest)
main()
```